# Looping through Set of results and Change Its Results In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle.
Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve the following scenario.

I have a table named table1 with ItemID, ItemName. 
And another table Inventory with ItemInventoryID, ItemDescription

I like to add a temporary column, "ItemStatus" to table1 during select statement.

And get the final result set with ItemID, ItemName, ItemStatus.

something like this

```
select ItemID, ItemName, 'False' as ItemStatus   
from table1;
```

(I want ItemStatus initially to be false.)

I need to update ItemStatus column on each row of this result before getting the output.
Based on following condition.

```
  declare temp Number;
  select count(*) INTO temp 
  from Inverntory
  where ItemInventoryID = ItemID    ///How do I get this ItemID for every row?

 IF(temp>0)
 THEN 
 UPDATE table1
 SET ITEMSTATUS = 'True';
 END IF;
```

How do I loop through the result set of

```
   select ItemInventoryID, ItemName, 'False' as ItemStatus
   from table1;
```

and update the ItemStatus value according to my condition and finally get the output.

Thanks In Advance,
Frank

Comment: If you're learning Oracle, first step should be to try to do everything without a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that ItemID is primary key in table1 and that it has a one-to-many relation with Inventory:

```
select a.ItemID
      ,a.ItemName
      ,case when count(b.ItemInventoryID) = 0 then 'False' else 'True' end as ItemStatus 
 from table1         a
 left join Inventory b on(
      b.ItemInventoryID =  a.ItemID
 )
group
   by a.ItemID
     ,a.ItemName;
```

The query does a left join, meaning that regardless if there is a match with Inventory or not, the row from table1 is still returned. The CASE construct, does what your temporary column would have done.